# "You can only post once every 40 minutes." Why do I get this error?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions

I'm trying to post a question on ServerFault, but I keep seeing this error:

```
You can only post once every 40 minutes.
```

**Why is this error showing? What do I need to do differently?**

Keep in mind:

- I have *not* asked a question on any SO sites in the last few days
- I have never asked a question on this SO site before
- I have over 100 reputation (woo hoo....)

[image]

Comment: aaaaaand it happened again, while trying to post *this* question.... I was eventually able to post it after a few minutes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This rate limit applies to users with less than 125 reputation, and all posts made by anyone from the same IP address on any Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange site count toward the limit, even if they are made by accounts with more than 125 reputation. If someone is sharing your IP address and also posting, then you may see this unexpectedly.

There are complete details on this and other rate limits in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/189912) (for your situation, search the page text for "40 minutes").

Comment: Same IP??? Not account? I share an office full of computer nerds! Seems like it will happen constantly....

Comment: Yep, same IP address. Fortunately it's not very difficult to reach 125 reputation.

Comment: I've been actively using SO for years.... just don't have many questions for which I can't find answers, I guess.

Comment: @AndrewRalon: You also get rep for *answering* questions.

Comment: @Sven: *facepalm*.... I'm aware.